# How can I exclude all the svn metadata while synchronizing with unison?

Tags: rsync, unison

How can I exclude all the svn metadata while synchronizing with unison?

So that all subfiles/folders are also ignored!

Thank you for you help

Answer (score 4):

In your preferences file:

```
ignore Name .svn
```

On the command line: `unison -ignore 'Name .svn'`.

It's a little weird to synchronize svn checkouts though. Usually people keep separate checkouts on separate machine and synchronize via the repository.

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude specific files or directories by putting "ignore" lines in your unison config file.  This should be ~/.unison/default.prf (or whatever the config file is for your specific sync profile).

[edited to just be where to put the ignore lines, since Gilles' answer solved the specific question better]

Comment: That only ignores `.svn` at the root of the synchronization tree, not in subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this myself, but according to the manual, the `--ignore "*/.svn/*"` option should help.

Comment: That just doesn't work (you need one of the keywords `Name`, `Path` or `Regex` in the pathspec). Where did you find it in the manual?

Comment: From the terminal, man unison: -ignore xxx add a pattern to the ignore list

Comment: ão: Ah, ok. Unison's terminology is indeed confusing here: it calls the whole `Name foo` a pattern, not just the `foo` part.